# Untiy UI: Text over sprite, behind Viewport mask?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I want a bunch of buttons that looks something like this:
[image]

It's in a grid layout group.  To get the text on top of the sprite, I used a canvas. This is what my hierarchy looks like:

```
1)Top Level UI (canvas)
  2)GridList (image)
    3)Viewport (image w/mask)
      4)Content (image w/grid layout group) 
        5)ButtonPrefab
          5.10)CanvasForText w/Sort Override
            5.11)Text1
            5.12)Text2
            5.13)Text3
          5.20)Sprite
```

But, the dang canvas with sort order override means the text draws outside the viewport's mask!

Any tips would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not limited to this hierarchy structure the simplest solution lies in the order of the UI elements.

By default the UI elements within one `Canvas` are rendered top to bottom so if you want something to be drawn on top just move it **below** the other elements in the hierarchy. This seems confusing since the background is kind of the first element in the Hierarchy but well .. it is how it is ;)

See [`UI.Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html)

> **Draw order of elements**
>
> UI elements in the Canvas are drawn in the same order they appear in the Hierarchy. The first child is drawn first, the second child next, and so on. If two UI elements overlap, the later one will appear on top of the earlier one.
>
> To change which element appear on top of other elements, simply reorder the elements in the Hierarchy by dragging them. The order can also be controlled from scripting by using these methods on the Transform component: `SetAsFirstSibling`, `SetAsLastSibling`, and `SetSiblingIndex`.

Your hierarchy should simply look like

```
Top Level UI (canvas)
|--GridList (image)
   |--Viewport (image w/mask)
      |--Content (image w/grid layout group) 
         |--ButtonPrefab
            |--Sprite
            |--Text1
            |--Text2
            |--Text3
```

Comment: Thanks... I could not imagine that was the appropriate order for the hierarchy, and I guess I got side-tracked with the override stuff reading old comments.  I appreciate the time to answer!